# How to fill non-contiguous ranges?

Tags: excel, vba

Current sheet layout
[image: Pic of current sheet layout]

I've a spreadsheet for managing a league. I am rewriting the entire thing for practice.

Is there a way shorten the repetitive loop?

People that check in have their names in column B. Once check in is completed, I fill an array with their names, randomize it, and place them on the cards shown on the right side.

```vb
Sub DivideIntoCards(playerArr As Variant)

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim remainder As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    
    remainder = UBound(playerArr) - LBound(playerArr) + 1
    
    If remainder Mod 4 = 0 Then
        'Number of players checked in creates equal cards of 4.
        
        Do Until remainder = 0
            j = 0
            'Fill card #1
            If i < 4 Then
                For i = 0 To 3
                    Cells(12 + j, 11) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #2
            ElseIf 4 <= i And i < 8 Then
                For i = 4 To 7
                    Cells(12 + j, 16) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #3
            ElseIf 8 <= i And i < 12 Then
                For i = 8 To 11
                    Cells(19 + j, 11) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #4
            ElseIf 12 <= i And i < 16 Then
                For i = 12 To 15
                    Cells(19 + j, 16) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #5
            ElseIf 16 <= i And i < 20 Then
                For i = 16 To 19
                    Cells(26 + j, 11) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #6
            ElseIf 20 <= i And i < 24 Then
                For i = 20 To 23
                    Cells(26 + j, 16) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #7
            ElseIf 24 <= i And i < 28 Then
                For i = 24 To 27
                    Cells(33 + j, 11) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #8
            ElseIf 28 <= i And i < 32 Then
                For i = 28 To 31
                    Cells(33 + j, 16) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #9
            ElseIf 32 <= i And i < 36 Then
                For i = 32 To 35
                    Cells(40 + j, 11) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #10
            ElseIf 36 <= i And i < 40 Then
                For i = 36 To 39
                    Cells(40 + j, 16) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #11
            ElseIf 40 <= i And i < 44 Then
                For i = 40 To 43
                    Cells(47 + j, 11) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            'Fill card #12
            ElseIf 44 <= i And i < 48 Then
                For i = 44 To 47
                    Cells(47 + j, 16) = playerArr(i)
                    remainder = remainder - 1
                    j = j + 1
                Next i
            End If
        Loop
        
    End If
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It appears that you have all the 'cards' for each player in one large array? Which is why you need to keep increasing `i` what you could try is make an array of arrays?

Comment: @mtholen I have each players real name in an array that i pass to this sub. This sub then arranges them in the cards to the right side of the picture. 

I've never made an array of arrays though, which might work if each card is an array itself. I'll look into that and see if I can get something to work.

The cards arent assigned to any sort of variable as of now. The for loop iterates over each card and places the people in the cards in groups of 4 as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
Sub DivideIntoCards(playerArr As Variant)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

Const PLAYER_PER_CARD = 3
Const START_ROW = 12
Const CARD_OFFSET = 7 'offset rows

cols = Array(11, 16) 'set predefined columns
    
players = UBound(playerArr) - LBound(playerArr) + 1

If players Mod PLAYER_PER_CARD = 0 Then
    
    cardCount = CInt(players / PLAYER_PER_CARD) - 1
    rPL = START_ROW
    
    For card = 0 To cardCount
        
        m = card Mod 2 'determine odd/even card
        If m = 0 Then rPL = START_ROW + (card / 2) * CARD_OFFSET 'increase row on uneven cards
        
        cPL = cols(m) 'choose correct column, based on odd/even card
                    
        For i = 0 To PLAYER_PER_CARD - 1
            plIndex = card * PLAYER_PER_CARD + i
            ws.Cells(rPL + i, cPL) = playerArr(plIndex)
        Next i
        
    Next
Else

    Response = MsgBox("The player count of " & players & _
    " cannot be divided in equals groups of " & PLAYER_PER_CARD & _
    " players.", vbCritical, "Player count Error")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This code works great. I think I'll be able to adapt it to a couple other situations that happen with this particular program I'm writing up. Thank you! (I tried giving you a positive reputation thingy, but it wont let me yet)

Comment: Glad I could help, If it has answered your question, simply mark the answer as the correct answer to help SO stay correct (i.e. reduce the number of unanswered questions)